# py2exe traits GUI

Tags: python, py2exe, traits, enthought

I am trying do pack my program with py2exe. It uses traits GUI. 
After moving the import statement in image.py in function "convert_image" out of the try block the crated exe fails at the second of the following points:

1: dist\traitsui\ui_traits.py: from .image.image import ImageLibrary 
2: dist\traitsui\image\image.py: from traitsui.ui_traits import HasBorder, HasMargin, Alignment

File Structure:

```
root
+-...
+-main.py
+-setup.py
+-dist
  +-...
  +-main.exe
  +-traitsui
    +-...
    +-ui_tratis.py
    +-image
      +-image.py
```

By adding the follow to the image.py

```
import sys
raise Exception(str(sys.path))
```

I get: Exception: ['C:\Users...\dist\.'] 
So it seems that the path is set right.

---

The error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "gui\FileSelect.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "traitsui\api.pyc", line 27, in <module>
  File "traitsui\basic_editor_factory.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "traitsui\editor_factory.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "traitsui\helper.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\dist\.\traitsui\ui_traits.py", line 158, in <module>
    from .image.image import ImageLibrary
  File "C:\Users\...\dist\.\traitsui\image\image.py", line 34, in <module>
    from traitsui.ui_traits import HasBorder, HasMargin, Alignment
ImportError: cannot import name HasBorder
```

---

setup.py: https://gist.github.com/2570888

Comment: for debugging I use "skip_archive": True

Comment: I just tested "skip_archive": False and it also dosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm it seams that there was somthing wrong with the Enthought package I used for the images.

So here the new setup file which works: 
https://gist.github.com/2570888

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `packages: ["traitsui"]` to `py2exe`'s options dictionary (with the `skip_archive` option).

I think that py2exe did not detect that the package `traitsui.ui_traits` is being used. You need to force it to include the whole `traitsui` package in the distribution.

**Note:** Just a guess, not tested.

Comment: hmm no I had added traitsui and now explicitly traitsui.ui_traits but that also didn't help. I added my setup.py above.